# Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working win 7 x 64

Tags: c++, crash, visual-studio-2010

After compiling one application in C++ using VS2010 on Win7 x64 appears the following:

> Microsoft Visual Studio has stopped working
>
> Problem signature: Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02: 10.0.40219.1
>
> Problem Signature 03: 4d5f2a73
>
> Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0
>
> Problem Signature 05: 10.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 06: 4d5f1237
>
> Problem Signature 07: 50c
>
> Problem Signature 08: 4b
>
> Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidCastException
>
> OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:    11274
>
> Additional information about the problem: LCID:   1033

I've installed VS2010 SP1, but I have no solution.

I also want to say the same VS2010 installed on Win7 x32 works fine.

Anyone knows How can I solve this?

Comment: The way to solve such problems is to report them to Microsoft so that they can **fix** them. Use http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ to report this bug.

Comment: It is a crash in ServiceProvider.GetService(), a common crash location.  Disable all add-ons, re-enable them one by one to find the troublemaker.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer why it reproduced on win7_x64.

1) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551576/any-compilation-in-visual-c-2010-express-crashes

2) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/11/if-you-are-seeing-intermittent-crashes-with-vs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue by registering the Ieproxy.dll manually.
To do this, follow these steps:
    Click Start  , type cmd in the search box.
    In the results list, right-click cmd , and then click Run as administrator to start an elevated command prompt.
    If you are prompted for an administrator password, type your password.If you are prompted for confirmation, click Continue .

```
For 32-bit operating systems, run the following command:
regsvr32 "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"   

For 64-bit operating systems, run the following command:
regsvr32 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```